# Homogeneous matrix has eight independent ratios of matrix elements?

Tags: computer-vision, projection-matrix, homogenous-transformation, matrix-vision

I'm reading some paper about computer vision. It looks like a simple fact but I can't understand. It is about homogenous [3x3] matrix that is used for planar projective transformation. And it is said to have eight independent ratios of matrix elements. I don't know what the ratio is, and what the eight independent ratios are? Please help me this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that two projective transformations `P` and `kP` are equivalent.

Consider a point in 2D: it can be expressed in non-homogeneous coordinates by a vector `[x,y]` . The same point expressed in homogeneous coordinates would be `[x',y',w]` where

```
x = x' / w
y = y' / w
```

As you can see, `w` behave as a scaling factor. 
Dividing the homogeneous coordinates by `w` you get `[x'/w, y'/w, 1] = [x,y,1]`. Thus a 2D point has only two degrees of freedom.

You can apply the same reasoning to a 3x3 matrix. Of the 9 elements only 8 are independent, while the last one can be seen as a scaling factor. It doesn't matter actually which one of the nine you choose.

For additional informations: [Homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)

EDIT:
The number of DOF is the number of independent parameters. In the example of the 2D point, even though we have three parameters (`x'`,`y'`,`w`), there are only two independent ratios: as I shown before, if you divide by `w` your firsts two parameters become fractions ("ratio" means division), while the third one is simply `1`.

For a 3D point it's the same reasoning, but you have to consider the `z` axes: a generic 3D point is `[x',y',z',w]` (4 parameters), but, if we divide by `w` it becomes `[x'/w, y'/w, z'/w, 1]` so three independent ratios.

I'm always dividing by `w` because the ratios `x'/w`, `y'/w`, `z'/w` have a particular meaning (non-homogeneous coordinates of the point), but to count the dof you can use any other parameter.

Let's consider the example of a 2x2 matrix (for a 3x3 it's the same, it's just longer to type):

```
m11  m12
m21  m22
```

4 parameters. Dividing by one of those at your choice (well, actually at my choice...), say `m12` it becomes

```
m11      1
---    
m12

m21     m22
---     ---
m12     m12
```

3 ratios so three degrees of freedom (for a generic 2x2 matrix). If, by instance, we have `m21 = m12` we would get

```
m11      
---      1
m12

        m22
 1      ---
        m12
```

thus in this case we would have only 2 dof! Don't get confused by the fact that you see `m11`,`m22` and `m12` (three parameters), because actually you can consider  `a = m11/m12` and `b= m22/m12`, thus it becomes

```
a   1
1   b
```

that means two independent parameters, thus two dof.

Hope it's clearer now

Comment: I can understand your example except the way to count. In case of 2D point, why does it has 2 DOF? How to count? And is there ambiguity between a point (2d point) and a transformation matrix. If we infer from 2D point case, it should be said that 3D point (a 4x1 vector not 3x3 matrix) has 8 independent ratios of matrix elements? Can you teach me an example of ratio and how to count the ratio? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Saphrosit. Your answer is very clear, informative and helpful. I now understand.

Comment: @HongAnTCAnAn don't forget to accept the answer (eventually you can also upvote) :)